# Average of all sums of subarrays

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures

I ran into a very hard question.

We have array of $n$ integers. for $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$. we want to set $c_{ij}$= Sum of all values in the range $i$ to $j$ of this array. we want to finding average of all possible $c_{ij}$ in this array. if 4 basic operation in math $(+,-,*,/)$ can be done in $O(1)$. the best algorithm can be works in $O(n)$.

this example is example from my made easy preparation class. anyone can describe me in simple words how this algorithm can be?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so clear what is meant by "sum of all values in the range $i$ to $j$". This probably means the sum of entries in *locations* $i$ to $j$.

Let us denote the entries of the array by $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. The entry $a_k$ is counted in those $c_{ij}$ such that $i \leq k \leq j$. There are $k(n+1-k)$ of these, out of a total of $\binom{n}{2}$. Therefore the quantity you are interested in is
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}} \sum_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k) a_k.
$$

---

Here is another interpretation, in which we sum all values in the array which belong to $\{i,\ldots,j\}$. Even this can be solved in linear time!

Suppose that some entry of the array has value $k$. What is its contribution to the average of the $c_{ij}$? It is counted in some $c_{ij}$ iff $i \leq k \leq j$. Out of the $\binom{n+1}{2}$ many $c_{ij}$'s, there are exactly $k(n+1-k)$ in which the entry is counted, therefore its contribution to the average is
$$
\frac{k(n+1-k)}{\binom{n+1}{2}} \cdot k = \frac{2k^2(n+1-k)}{(n+1)n}.
$$
Summing this over all values in the array, we obtain the desired $O(n)$ algorithm.

Comment: Take it as an exercise.

Comment: It's basic combinatorics. Pick up a textbook on discrete math.